# Dynamically change texture of Ellipse in kivy, python

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, textures

I want to add a texture to Ellipse from python code.

.kv file:

```
    <User>:
        user_name: username
        user_pic: userpic
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '40dp'
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        padding: 2
        BoxLayout:
            id: userpic
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            canvas.before:
                Ellipse:
                    group: 'pic'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

python code:
    class User(BoxLayout):
        user_name = ObjectProperty(None)
        def init(self, texture, name):
            self.ids.user_pic.canvas.get_group['pic'][0].texture = texture
            self.user_name.text = name

some portion of the other code:
user = User()
    img = np.array(json.loads(user_dtls[i][1])).reshape(56, 56, 3)
                img = img.astype(np.uint8)
                img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
                texture = Texture.create(size=(56, 56))
                texture.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
                user.init(texture, 'demo')
                self.uh.add_widget(user)
```

getting following error:

```
self.ids.user_pic.canvas.get_group['pic'][0].texture = texture
```

File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 841, in 
kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Comment: I would be happy to look into this if you post a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps using `userpic` in one place and `user_pic` in another is causing some difficulties?

Comment: Also, `get_group` is a method, not a list, so it should appear as `get_group('pic')`

Comment: Also, your `pic` group is being created inside the `before` group (you are using `canvas.before`), so `canvas.get_group` should be `canvas.before.get_group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in spite of not having a minimal reproducible example, here is what I think are your main problems:

- using `userpic` in one place and `user_pic` in another
- `get_group` is a method, not a list, so it should appear as `get_group('pic')`
- your `pic` group is being created inside the `before` group (you are using `canvas.before`), so `canvas.get_group` should be `canvas.before.get_group`